# replacing variables in a conditional statement by functions

Tags: functions, proof-writing, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Considering following conditional statement as an example:
$$\forall A,C,E\in\mathbb Z^*,\forall B,D,F\in\mathbb Z^+\left(\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}\rightarrow\frac{E}{F}\times\frac{A}{B}=\frac{E}{F}\times\frac{C}{D}\right)$$
I want to prove that a statement like below which states you can replace variables of above statement by functions is true:
$$\left(\forall x\in\mathbb Z^*,\forall y\in\mathbb Z^+\left(\frac{x}{GCD\left(x,y\right)}\in\mathbb Z^*\right)\wedge\forall g,i\in\mathbb Z^+,\forall h\in\mathbb Z^*\left(\frac{g\times i}{GCD\left(g,h\right)\times GCD\left(h,i\right)}\in\mathbb Z^+\right)\wedge\forall A,C,E\in\mathbb Z^*,\forall B,D,F\in\mathbb Z^+\left(\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}\rightarrow\frac{E}{F}\times\frac{A}{B}=\frac{E}{F}\times\frac{C}{D}\right)\right)\rightarrow\forall x,A,C,h\in\mathbb Z^*,\forall y,B,D,g,i\in\mathbb Z^+\left(\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}\rightarrow\frac{\frac{x}{GCD\left(x,y\right)}}{\frac{g\times i}{GCD\left(g,h\right)\times GCD\left(h,i\right)}}\times\frac{A}{B}=\frac{\frac{x}{GCD\left(x,y\right)}}{\frac{g\times i}{GCD\left(g,h\right)\times GCD\left(h,i\right)}}\times\frac{C}{D}\right)$$
Now any tip on how I should approach this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any special work, since the $=$ rules in logic take care of all this automatically.

For example, $= Intro$ is defined as follows:

$t=t$ with $t$ *any* term. Thus, the following are all good applications of this rule:

I.

$a=a$ ('typical' use of $= Intro$)

II.

$a * b = a * b$ (you can use complex terms as well)

Likewise, $=Elim$ is defined as follows:

$\varphi(t_1)$

$t_1 = t_2$

$\therefore \varphi(t_2)$  where $\varphi(t_2)$ is the result of substituting some or all of the terms $t_1$ occurring in $\varphi(t_1)$ with $t_2$

Thus, below are some perfectly acceptable applications of $= Elim$:

III.

$P(a)$

$a=b$

$\therefore P(b)$ ('typical'use of $= Elim$)

IV.

$P(a,a)$

$a = b$

$\therefore P(a,b)$ (you don't have to replace all $a$'s with $b$'s)

V.

$P(a*b)$

$a * b = c * d$

$\therefore P(c*d)$ (you can substitute complex terms involving functions)

So, your statement is easily provable using this rule, since the consequent is already a logical necessity:

1. $$\frac{A}{B} = \frac{C}{D} \qquad Assumption$$
2. $$\frac{\frac{x}{GCD\left(x,y\right)}}{\frac{g\times i}{GCD\left(g,h\right)\times GCD\left(h,i\right)}}\times\frac{A}{B}=\frac{\frac{x}{GCD\left(x,y\right)}}{\frac{g\times i}{GCD\left(g,h\right)\times GCD\left(h,i\right)}}\times\frac{A}{B}  \qquad = Intro$$

3.$$\frac{\frac{x}{GCD\left(x,y\right)}}{\frac{g\times i}{GCD\left(g,h\right)\times GCD\left(h,i\right)}}\times\frac{A}{B}=\frac{\frac{x}{GCD\left(x,y\right)}}{\frac{g\times i}{GCD\left(g,h\right)\times GCD\left(h,i\right)}}\times\frac{C}{B}  \qquad = Elim \: 1,2$$

4. $$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}\rightarrow\frac{\frac{x}{GCD\left(x,y\right)}}{\frac{g\times i}{GCD\left(g,h\right)\times GCD\left(h,i\right)}}\times\frac{A}{B}=\frac{\frac{x}{GCD\left(x,y\right)}}{\frac{g\times i}{GCD\left(g,h\right)\times GCD\left(h,i\right)}}\times\frac{C}{D} \qquad \rightarrow Intro \: 1-3$$

Comment: Thank you, I haven't studied pure logic and hadn't seen the structure you're using, apparently I need to study it.

Comment: @Pooria You're welcome. Yes, just look for 'logic rules involving identity'.

Comment: Of course I'm sure those rules can be proved if they need to be, Problem was I was trying to prove some part of them by writing some statements as you saw :)

Comment: So I got confused a little by something, can a single number be considered a term, like 1 or 2 or 999 or whatever? I think yes because it is maybe a constant symbol?

Comment: @Pooria Yes, exactly: for numbers we can use constant symbols, which are (atomic) terms.  Although please note that in Peano Arithmetic, there is only one constant symbol for the number 0 ... to represent the number 1, you use the term $s(0)$, where $s$ is the 'successor' function. So $999$ would be a really long term!

Comment: One more question, shouldn't we write $\therefore\varphi(t_2//t_1)$ instead of $\therefore\varphi(t_2)$ ?

Comment: @Pooria Yes, sorry, that's exactly what it is. I'm just used to just writing $\varphi(t_2)$ when the context makes it clear I really mean $\varphi(t_2/t_1)$.

Comment: Thank you for being a great teacher, also I wonder if in the case there were more than one statements of terms being equal to each other, it'd be correct to write something like this:
$$\varphi(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)$$
$$t_1=t_5$$
$$t_3=t_6$$
$$\therefore\varphi(t_5//t_1,t_2,t_6//t_3,t_4)$$

Comment: @Pooria That is certainly logically valid, and a formal proof system *could* define a rule as such, but I have never seen any actual system that does so ... In all systems I know of you have to do this one by one.

Comment: So one by one, to prove $\left(E=A\wedge F=B\right)\rightarrow\frac{E}{F}=\frac{A}{B}$ which of following two ways is chosen in logic systems?
one:
$$\frac{E}{F}=\frac{E}{F}$$
$$E=A$$
$$\therefore\frac{E}{F}=\frac{A}{F}$$
-
$$\frac{E}{F}=\frac{A}{F}$$
$$F=B$$
$$\therefore\frac{E}{F}=\frac{A}{B}$$
Two:
$$\frac{E}{F}=\frac{E}{F}$$
$$E=A$$
$$\therefore\frac{E}{F}=\frac{A}{F}$$
-
$$\frac{A}{F}=\frac{A}{F}$$
$$F=B$$
$$\therefore\frac{A}{F}=\frac{A}{B}$$
concluding $\left(E=A\wedge F=B\right)\rightarrow\frac{E}{F}=\frac{A}{F}\wedge\frac{A}{F}=\frac{A}{B}$ thus the intended statement

Comment: @Pooria both work!!

Comment: @Pooria Correct. But please do note that you don't need that $a=b$ and $c=d$ to go from $\frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{d}$ to something like $e*\frac{a}{c}=e*\frac{b}{d}$. When I said 'one at a time', I meant one *term* at a time .. but the term can be a complex one, like $\frac{a}{c}$.

Comment: Fantastic and I assume $\rightarrow$Intro 1-3 of the proof you've provided can be considered a new formula variables of which are A,B,C,D,g,h,i,x,y; also just to be clear we have instantiated formulas by variables and so instantiation can be done using both variables and constants?  I edited last comment a bit :)

Comment: @Pooria Oh, I see what you mean. Eh, that depends on the specifics of the particular proof system you are using: some proof systems don't allow you to have unquantified variables at all, so all terms would have to involve constants. However, if the system you use allows for free variables during the proof, then yes, you can also use them in the terms used for the identity rules.

Comment: I suspect what I meant doesn't have anything to do with quantification, to make it clear lets assume as in your proof our formula is $a*b=a*b$ then we can have both of two instantiations $\varphi(10,38)$ and $\varphi(\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d})$ now you see first one was done using constants and second using variables, and hopefully I'm not making any mistake.

Comment: @Pooria In many logic systems, the letters in the beginning of the alphabet (like $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are used for constants ... variables would be letters at the end, like $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Comment: Wow thanks god it makes so much sense now, thought they were variables and so this made me confused as hell :)

Comment: One last question, is this correct?
if $\varphi(t_1//t_3,t_2)$ and $t_2=t_4$ are correct then $\varphi(t_1//t_3,t_4//t_2)$ is also correct (multiple partial substitutions)

Comment: @Pooria Yes, correct!

Comment: thanks for all your answers helped me a lot, also in case I had some more questions about logic would you mind if I go ahead and ask you?

Comment: @Pooria You can always ask!  Whether I have time to answer is another matter but I certainly won't mind.

Comment: Thanks it's Fantastic, so I was thinking about two things, first if stating that any term is equal to itself (term=term) would need any proof (Not that I have any doubt it is equal) and second in cases where we take term=term as intro for our proof, is there anyway to avoid writing the same term twice, like using function symbols instead of writing body of function everytime?

Comment: @Pooria Most formal proof systems have an explicit rule (called $= Intro$) to derive $term = term$ (using no premises, of course). This is what I did in line 2 in the proof above. As to the second question ... I am not sure what you are asking ... can you give an example?

Comment: First to make sure I'm not making some huge mistake, I should ask did you use the formula $\varphi(x,y) : x\times y=x\times y$ in your proof? also as for that example I mean like in your proof we assign a symbol to the term $\frac{\frac{x}{GCD\left(x,y\right)}}{\frac{g\times i}{GCD\left(g,h\right)\times GCD\left(h,i\right)}}\times\frac{A}{B}$ and then intro would be like symbol=symbol instead of writing the whole term two times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51214/discussion-between-bram28-and-pooria).

Comment: @Pooria Well, I did not introduce $x \times y = x \times y$ and then substitute anything for the $x$ or $y$ in subsequent steps. Rather, as you say, I saw that whole one big formula as one term and used $= Elim$ to say it is equal to itself on line 2 in just 1 step.

Comment: I agree I've already turned comments section into a chat section! I think I understand what you mean, we don't specify any formula that our intro would've been achieved by instantiating it. we just identify occurrances of $t_1$ and substitute $t_2$ for some of them.